# How make users own their data in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Currently, if you’re logged in, you’ll be able to see all the products, no matter
which user you’re logged in as.how can i show merchants only the products that belongs to them.

i try this

views.py

```
def users_homepage(request):
    product=Product.objects.filter(merchant=request.user).order_by('date_added')
```

and i get this error "  Cannot query "mustapha": Must be "Merchant" instance"

my models.py

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
class Product(models.Model):
    merchant=models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user to get a merchant instance and the use that to query products.

```
def users_homepage(request):
    merchant = Merchant.objects.get(user=request.user)
    product = Product.objects.filter(merchant=merchant).order_by('date_added')
```

Another way to do this is using [default] related name.

```
def users_homepage(request):
    product = Product.objects.filter(merchant=request.user.merchant).order_by('date_added')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def users_homepage(request):
    product=Product.objects.filter(merchant__user=request.user).order_by('date_added')
```